# DAX: Cumulative Completion Rate with Month Slicer

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to calculate cumulative completion rate by all users over moths, the issue is that in the below table for ex when I filter on october it divides users who finished till october / all users except those who finished in November.

I have a dim_date table which is connect to the data table, the retaltion is between Date from dim_date and Completion Date from Data table
Also in dim date table im numbering the months 1,2,3,4 etc

| ID | Completion_status | Completion Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |  |
| 2 | 0 |  |
| 3 | 0 |  |
| 4 | 0 |  |
| 5 | 0 |  |
| 6 | 1 | 11/1/2022 |
| 7 | 1 | 11/1/2022 |
| 8 | 1 | 11/1/2022 |
| 9 | 1 | 11/2/2022 |
| 10 | 1 | 11/1/2022 |
| 11 | 1 | 11/6/2022 |
| 12 | 1 | 11/4/2022 |
| 13 | 1 | 11/2/2022 |
| 14 | 1 | 10/13/2022 |
| 15 | 1 | 10/14/2022 |
| 16 | 1 | 10/14/2022 |
| 17 | 1 | 10/13/2022 |
| 18 | 1 | 10/15/2022 |
| 19 | 1 | 10/13/2022 |
| 20 | 1 | 10/13/2022 |
| 21 | 1 | 10/13/2022 |
| 22 | 1 | 10/13/2022 |
| 23 | 1 | 10/18/2022 |
| 24 | 1 | 10/13/2022 |
| 25 | 1 | 10/13/2022 |
| 26 | 1 | 10/13/2022 |
| 27 | 1 | 10/13/2022 |
| 28 | 1 | 9/10/2022 |
| 29 | 1 | 9/8/2022 |

the formula I use

```
Completion% = 
VAR comp rate = SUM(Table[completion_status]) / count(Table[ID])
Return

CALCULATE(Table[Completion%],filter(ALL(Dim_Date),Dim_Date[Month Number] <= MAX(Dim_Date[Month Number])))
```

the expected result when I filter

on september is 2/29 = 7%

on october is 16/29 = 55%

on November is 24/29 = 83%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
=
VAR SelectedMonth =
    MIN( Dim_Date[Month Number] )
VAR CumulativeTotal =
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS( 'Table' ),
        FILTER(
            ALL( Dim_Date ),
            Dim_Date[Month Number] <= SelectedMonth
                && NOT ( ISBLANK( Dim_Date[Month Number] ) )
        )
    )
VAR CountAllRows =
    CALCULATE( COUNTROWS( 'Table' ), ALL( Dim_Date ) )
RETURN
    DIVIDE( CumulativeTotal, CountAllRows )
```

I'm presuming that *Dim_Date[Month Number]* is blank when *Table[Completion Date]* is blank.

You may want to replace `ALL` with, for example, `ALLSELECTED`, depending on your required set-up.